# How does this higher order function work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

This code is confusing me.

Where does the inner function get the value for x.

```
function createMultiplier(multiplier) {
  return function(x) {
    return x * multiplier
  }
}

let doubleMe = createMultiplier(2);
```

Comment: when you call `doubleMe(123)`

Comment: sidenote can be written as `const createMultiplier = multiplier => (x => multiplier * x)`

Comment: `createMultiplier` returns the inner function (with the `multiplier` value assigned), which is then assigned to `doubleMe`, which you can then call like so: `doubleMe(42)`

Answer (score 2):

This is called currying, what happens is that in the function `createMultiplier` you get a function and then when you execute that function you pass the parameter `x`

If you want to execute the function inside the function immediately, you can use this code `createMultiplier(2)(5)`

If you use console logs you can understand better what happens, I made an example bellow, so you can see first you only get a function and then you can pass the parameter `x`

```js
function createMultiplier(multiplier) {
  return function(x) {
    return x * multiplier
  }
}

const doubleMe = createMultiplier(2);
console.log(doubleMe)
const result = doubleMe(5)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

The inner function will get the value `x`. When you invoke: `doubleMe(16)`, for example.

When you call `createMultiplier(2)` you are setting the `multiplier` value.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to try and visual what happens when you call `createMultiplier(2)`.

This will create a function that would look like this:

```
function doubleMe(x) {
  return x * 2; // 2 is the multiplier that we supplied to 'createMultiplier'
}

let answer = doubleMe(4);
// answer = 8;
```

another example:

```
let tripleMe = createMultiplier(3);

// is the same as writing this
function tripleMe(x) {
  return x * 3;
}

let answer = tripleMe(3);
// answer = 9;
```